# Backbone.js: How to utilize router.navigate to manipulate browser history?

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I am writing something like a registration process containing several steps, and I want to make it a single-page like system so after some studying Backbone.js is my choice.

Every time the user completes the current step they will click on a NEXT button I create and I use the router.navigate method to update the url, as well as loading the content of the next page and doing some fancy transition with javascript.

Result is, URL is updated which the page is not refreshed, giving a smooth user experience. However, when the user clicks on the back button of the browser, the URL gets updated to that of a previous step, but the content stays the same. My question is through what way I can capture such an event and currently load the content of the previous step and present that to the user? Or even better, can I rely on browser cache to load that previously loaded page?

EDIT: in particular, I'm trying something like mentioned in [this article](http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use route.navigate but let the router decide which form to display based on the current route.

exemple :

a link in your current form of the registration process :

```
<a href="#form/2" ...
```

in the router definition :

```
routes:{
  "form/:formNumber" : "gotoForm"
},

gotoForm:function(formNumber){
 // the code to display the correct form for the current url based on formNumber
}
```

and then use `Backbone.history.start()` to bootstrap routing

Comment: Well thanks for the reply, but I'm really doing this in a way that I don't want the presence of hashtag. In particular I'm trying something like in this article: http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Comment: After some more work I think I have figured it out, I need to called navigate with trigger: true to trigger the router's function which does the update of the content. No hashtag!